# Referencing data in Vaadin Combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I've been having trouble mapping data to a combobox in vaadin. My intention was to have a few comboboxes in a window and a button that the user can press when he is done making selections in the comboboxes.

I want to add a listener to the button, and I know that it is easy to do, but then when the "buttonPressed", or whatever its called, runs I would like it to do something like this(pseudocode):

```
ComboBox c1;
ComboBox c2;
Button b = new Button(new Button.ClickListener(){
    public void buttonPressed(Event e){
        dostuff(c1.getSelected(), c2.getSelected));
    }
});
```

Is this possible or am I missing something? Sorry if I sound stupid but I have googled and the examples are to advanced for me and omits stuff that I need to see.

Comment: is c1 and c2 setImmediate(true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your pseudo code should work fine; I can't see any problems with what you are doing here. Mind you, you haven't actually said what the problem actually is...

BTW: a ComboBox is called a Select in Vaadin, and getSelected is getValue - i.e. the value of a Select is the selected item.

Comment: I was uncertain if this was the proper way to use Vaadin, that was the acutal problem. Another question, if you would be so kind and also look at that, is how to map a object. I can just add Strings to the combobox and do so if checks to see what object that is referenced, but what if I actually want to att a object that I have written? Simply implement toString to make it look correct in the combobox?

Comment: These questions are probably better addressed in the Vaadin forum; you can get the Select to use any property of the object as the caption - see https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.selecting.html for more details.

Comment: Actually, ComboBox extends Select, so you can use either one. Visually they produce pretty much the same component.